# How to iterate through nested arrays with jsredner

Tags: jquery, arrays, nested, jsrender

I have the following json:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Billy in the Lowground",
      "Key":"A",
      "chords":[
         [
            "G",
            "",
            "D",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "C",
            "",
            "G",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "C",
            "",
            "G",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "A",
            "",
            "D",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "G",
            "",
            "D",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "C",
            "",
            "G",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "C",
            "",
            "G",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "D",
            "",
            "G",
            ""
         ],
         "Em",
         "",
         "",
         "B7",
         "Em",
         "",
         [
            "C",
            "",
            "G",
            ""
         ],
         [
            "D",
            "",
            "G",
            ""
         ]
      ]
   }
];
```

Under chords, I'm mapping each measure to a spot in the chords array and then each measure is another array that corresponds to the # of beats in a measure. In this case 4 beats.

So I was having problems figuring out how to iterate over nested arrays but while I was writing up this question I think I figured out the answer, but is this the best way to access and iterate over nested arrays:

```
 <script id="chord-tpl" type="text/x-jsrender">  
                {{for chords}}
                    <tr>
                        {{for #parent.data[#index]}}

                            <td>{{:#parent.data[#index]}}</td>
                        {{/for}}
                    </tr>
                {{/for}}

        </script>
```

Also I was wondering if there's a way to see how many times you have iterated over the array and do something based on the # of times,

e.g.

```
for( i=0; i == chords.length; $i++ ) {
   if( i % 4 ) {
       // start new table row
   }
   else {
       // echo out table cell
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> is this the best way to access and iterate over nested arrays

You can modify your template to this:

```
{{for chords}}
    <tr>
       {{for #data}}
           <td>{{:#data}}</td>
       {{/for}}
    </tr>
{{/for}}
```

---

> I was wondering if there's a way to see how many times you have iterated over the array and do something based on the # of times

You allowed to introduce a variable.

```
{{for chords ~count=chords.length}}
```

More details you can find [here](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/scenarios/02_separators-scenario.html)

---

Also you are able to debug your template with ["helper functions"](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/09_helper-functions.html)
This snippet can help you

```
$.views.helpers({
  debug:function(){
     console.dir(this);
  }
});
```